# Is it possible to create multiple Swagger document URLs?

Tags: c#, api, swagger, documentation, swashbuckle

I have a website which is using Web API 2 and I am using Swashbuckle Swagger to generate API documentation and export the JSON configuration for Azure API Management. In my scenario it would be ideal if the APIs could be grouped by a value defined in the Swagger document URL (http://example.com/swagger/{my-api-group}). However, after some research I could not find a way to implement this.

From what I can understand, at the moment in order for me to change the Swagger export file, I need to restart the environment each time there is a change and this is not ideal in my scenario.

I have tried to see if I can get the open source code from the NuGet package to see if I could understand the inner workings of Swashbuckle. Furthermore, I am aware that this can be achieved using "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore", but this is not an option since I am integrating this feature in a big .NET Framework solution which would be a staggering task to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, here is an example:
http://swagger-net-test-multiapiversions.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

And the source code for that is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/tree/MultiApiVersions

The key to that is this piece on the configuration:

```
// If your API has multiple versions, use "MultipleApiVersions" instead of "SingleApiVersion".
// In this case, you must provide a lambda that tells Swagger-Net which actions should be
// included in the docs for a given API version. Like "SingleApiVersion", each call to "Version"
// returns an "Info" builder so you can provide additional metadata per API version.
//
c.MultipleApiVersions(
    (apiDesc, targetApiVersion) => targetApiVersion.Equals("default", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||     
                                   apiDesc.Route.RouteTemplate.StartsWith(targetApiVersion, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), 
                    (vc) =>
                    {
                        vc.Version("default", "Swagger_Test");
                        vc.Version("v1_0", "Swagger_Test V1_0");
                        vc.Version("v2_0", "Swagger_Test V2_0");
                    });
```

Another option could be leveraging the filter on the latest UI:

- http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Default
- http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Big
- http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Image

Comment: I do not want to lose the versioning of my APIs in order to be able to group certain APIs together.

Comment: So you already have versioning... but you want further grouping?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: You mentioned you are aware that this can be achieved using "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   Do you have a link to that?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is not grouping but filtering:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Default
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Big

Comment: Yes, in fact I used filtering to achieve this, but I wanted to know if there was something that I could do which was related to Swashbuckle in anyway.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is to use an IDocumentFilter to drop additional .json files with groups of what you need, but that will certainly be a pain, I have some examples filters here: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L390

Comment: If you can think of a better to approach this I can add it to Swagger-Net

Comment: Thanks! If I find one, I will post it here.